# How to style the string of a ListView added programmatically?

Tags: android, android-listview

Android newbie here. I'm using [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) tutorial to show some rows that I fetch from a web server using JSON. Even though I know that the correct approach is to define the rows as a external resource I opted for the array method explained there. Is there a way to have mixed styles within the rows? For example, instead of an array of countries,  an array of country code and country name where the country code would have a larger font size.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but you will have to create your own Adapter to return a View for the row. That View will have 2 TextView's. Each TextView can have a different font size.

For more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Comment: Hey thank you. That seems to be what I'm looking for. It looks obvious but for a newbie it's hard to know what to look for.